Continuity of Functional involving composition with linear operator
In my analysis class we studied continuity and various other properties of functionals of the form $I\lbrack x, u, \nabla u\rbrack = \int_\Omega L(x, u(x), \nabla u(x)) dx $ in the context of calculus of variation. I was wondering if we can extend this like so:
Let $\Omega_1, \Omega_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be two bounded, open sets, $\{f_j\}\subset H^k(\Omega_2), k \geq 1$ be a (bounded) sequence of functions so that they converge weakly to some $ f \in H^k(\Omega_2)$, so $f_j \rightharpoonup f$. Additionally I take a sequence of linear, bounded operators, $K_j \in L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$ so that $K(x), K_j(x)\in \Omega_2\forall x \in\Omega_1, j \in \mathbb{N}$ , $K_j \rightarrow K$ strongly.
Now I want to show the following:
$$
\mathrm{I}\lbrack \psi_j\rbrack = \mathrm{I}\lbrack(f_j, K_j)\rbrack = \int_{\Omega_1} f_j(K_j(x)) dx \rightarrow \int_{\Omega_1} f(K(x)) dx = \mathrm{I}\lbrack(f, K)\rbrack
$$
What I have done so far is the following

Since $\{f_j\} \subset H^k(\Omega_2)$ is bounded and $k\geq 1$ we have strong convergence in $L^2$, $f_j \rightarrow f$
If I assume that each of the $K_j$'s would be an invertible operator and that $k> \frac{n}{2}$ I could proceed as follows:
Because the $K_j$'s are linear operators between finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vectorspaces I can view them as a sequence of matrices, so $K_j(x) = A_jx$ for some $A_j \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ These $A_j$'s are then also invertible and I can integrate with the transformation formula to get
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega_1} |f_j(A_jx) - f(Ax)|dx &= \int_{A_j(\Omega_1)} |f_j(x) - f(A A_j^{-1}x)||\det A_j^{-1}| dx \\ &\leq \int_{\Omega_2} |f_j(x) - f(A A_j^{-1}x)||\det A_j^{-1}|dx
\end{align}
Since we assumed $k> \frac{n}{2}$ we know that each of the functions ocurring in the integral are Hölder-continuous and hence uniformly bounded. So if we take the limit, we can take it inside the integral and by continuity of $f$ inside the function to get convergence.

Is it possible to show convergence if I don't assume the operators to be invertible? To me it seems like it should work, however I was unable to deal with the composition of $f$ and $K$, maybe it works with a growth condition (akin to the Nemytskii operator theorem ) ?
